# additional qry params not working

Tags: mysql

[Group By First Query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290746/group-by-first-query-in-mysql)

so I asked the above and got a great response

but how do I add in where `homematchingid !=0` and `awaymatchingid !=0`?

I've tried the below, but neither are working.

```
SELECT MIN(`Date`) AS `Date`, MIN(`Time`) AS `Time`,
    `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus`
FROM `20121208`
where `HomeMatchingId`!= 0,`AwayMatchingId`!= 0
GROUP BY `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus` 
HAVING `RunningStatus`= 1
```

and

```
SELECT MIN(`Date`) AS `Date`,MIN(`Time`) AS `Time`,
    `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus`
FROM `20121208`
GROUP BY `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus` 
HAVING `RunningStatus`=1,`HomeMatchingId`!=0,`AwayMatchingId`!=0);
```

Comment: Have you Tried using **and** instead of comma 



    `SELECT MIN(`Date`) AS `Date`, MIN(`Time`) AS `Time`,
        `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus`
    FROM `20121208`
    where `HomeMatchingId`!= 0 and `AwayMatchingId`!= 0
    GROUP BY `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus` 
    HAVING `RunningStatus`= 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the comma in the where clause with a logical operator like AND or OR.

```
SELECT MIN(`Date`) AS `Date`, MIN(`Time`) AS `Time`,
`HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus`
FROM `20121208`
where `HomeMatchingId`!= 0 AND `AwayMatchingId`!= 0
GROUP BY `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus` 
HAVING `RunningStatus`= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try <>  instead of !=

```
SELECT MIN(`Date`) AS `Date`, MIN(`Time`) AS `Time`,
    `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus`
FROM `20121208`
where `HomeMatchingId`<> 0 AND `AwayMatchingId`<> 0
GROUP BY `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus` 
HAVING `RunningStatus`= 1
```

and

```
SELECT MIN(`Date`) AS `Date`,MIN(`Time`) AS `Time`,
    `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus`
FROM `20121208`
GROUP BY `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus` 
HAVING `RunningStatus`=1 AND `HomeMatchingId`<>0 AND `AwayMatchingId`<>0;
```

Comment: already tried both versions with <> 0 and !=0, but neither are working

Comment: CREATE TABLE `kickofftimes` (
 `Date` INT(11) NULL,
 `Time` TIME NULL,
 `HomeMatchingId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `AwayMatchingId` INT(11) NULL,
 `RunningStatus` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: you need to change comma in where clause to AND, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT MIN(`Date`) AS `Date`, MIN(`Time`) AS `Time`,
    `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus`
FROM `20121208`
WHERE `HomeMatchingId`<>0 AND `AwayMatchingId`<>0
GROUP BY `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus` 
HAVING `RunningStatus`=1
```

and

```
SELECT MIN(`Date`) AS `Date`,MIN(`Time`) AS `Time`,
    `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus`
FROM `20121208`
GROUP BY `HomeMatchingId`,`AwayMatchingId`,`RunningStatus` 
HAVING `RunningStatus`=1 AND `HomeMatchingId`<>0 AND `AwayMatchingId`<>0;
```